# Restricting the download of images depending on size of the device

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

We are are using 3 size images for 3 different devices. For Example, mobile-banner.png, tablet-banner.png, desktop-banner.png are having same look and feel; but having different size and resolutions. Can we restrict the download(Not show/hide) of irrelevant images depending on size of the device. The performance can be drastically improved if we avoid download of mobile and tablet image for desktop. Similar way for other devices. I can see the images getting downloaded even though they(mobile and tablet images) are not used in Desktop. Kindly help.

Comment: There are [a](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2014/05/responsive-images-done-right-guide-picture-srcset/) [few](https://css-tricks.com/responsive-images-css/) solutions to this. ;)

Comment: Note : images should be using <img> tag and content will come from CMS. So no media queries please. There is big editable list of images coming from CMS dynamically rendered in to the page. each image has 3 sets of image for mobile, tablet and desktop/laptop which is  requirement  from client

Comment: I was pointing you to the `srcset` attribute for `<img />` tags - which you could probably use these days: http://caniuse.com/#search=srcset

Comment: You say "size of the device" but in fact you need "mobile vs tablet vs desktop". Two different beasts. I could have a 500mbps connection and ridiculously low resolution.

Answer (score 0):

from what i understand from this question is that you want to add more of like a responsive behaviour.If it is so,you can restrict the image size using jquery.Some what like this:

```js
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

if ( $(window).width() > 739) {      
  //Add your javascript for large screens here 
} 
else {
  //Add your javascript for small screens here 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for trying:) But my requirement is different. In developer tools i can see all 3 set of images for type of devices getting downloaded. which downgrades performance. Also I can not avoid using 3 images because there is slight shape change as per requirement and so I can not resize which will spoil the shape. Here image size means size on disk and not dimension or resolution of the image. I need the downloading of only those image which is required for that specific device and images related to other devices should not be downloaded.